# Fetching and displaying more records on UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Hi I have about 2500 records to be displayed. All these data are coming from a MySQL database. The data will be shown 25 at a time in UITableview similar to itunes store. On click of Load More, I need to fetch the next 25 records.

Note:There is no image only texts.

Have any one done anything similar?Give me the sample code.

Comment: You need the code for fetching the records from the database or loading them into the UITableView?

Comment: you must be using query to fetch first 25 records.. So for next 25 records fire another query in Load Click event then use Reloading of TableView. and do this for every time you click load button....

Comment: Can you send me any sample code link?

Comment: Can you show the code you have and identify what problems you're hitting?  How are you exposing the data from your database? webservice? rest?

Comment: I am using NSXMLParserDelegate..NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest 
         requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

Answer (score 1):

```
 first in .h define int row;

and now in viewDidLoad: row=25;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if([your array count]>row)
return row+1;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 if (indexPath.row<row)
 {
  cell.textLabel.text=@"Your Text"; 
 }
else{
   cell.textLabel.text=@"Load More";
}
}
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
   if (indexPath.row==row) 
 {
     row=row+25;
      [tableView reloadData];

  }
```

`
    hope this will help you..